# Bundle is always null

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom notification. In this notification I have a Button. My problem is when I click the button I can't seem to pass any extra to the new class.

This is the code I am using on the button:

```
// notification button
Intent switchIntent = new Intent(context, SecondClass.class);
switchIntent.putExtra("passThis", passThisValue);
PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, switchIntent, 0);
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingSwitchIntent);
```

The class I want the extras:

```
public class SecondClass extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
     String id = extras.getString("passThis"); } }
```

Bundle is allways null. I only posted the part of the code where I think the problem is, if you need the full code I will edit my post.

I am not doing this correctly? How should I pass a value to a class on a Notification Button Event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("passThis", passThisValue);
switchIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Comment: This is working, but I find quite strange because I had already tried this aproach. The only difference is that now I unistalled the app first, made the changes and re-installed. Well, is working... thanks!

Comment: @Ravers thanks..can you accept this as your answer. it helps.

Answer (score 1):

the above code doesnt pass the data as bundle its just going as intent extra.... you have to call

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("YOURKEY");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the passed Bundle from notification Override an onNewIntent to your activity like the code below. Hope this help.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras!=null) {
        String id = extras.getString("passThis");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a tutorial about this for one of my neighbors in case you want to review it. Here's the [link](http://toomanytutorials.blogspot.com/2015/12/passing-data-between-android-activities.html)