# Bundle is null when starting an activity from a listener using intent

Tags: java, android

The bundle is null when I use this code. The Logcat shows:

```
 onSuccess: starting activity with intent
 getTokenFromIntent: bundle IS null (true)
```

**MyListenerService.java**

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

 bundle.putString("Name",message.getName());

 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 intent.putExtras(bundle);

 Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: starting activity with intent");
 startActivity(intent);
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 TokenMessage token = null;

 Intent intent = getIntent();
 if (intent!=null) {
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

     if (bundle!=null) {

          token = new TokenMessage();
          token.setName(bundle.getString("Name"));

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "getTokenFromIntent: bundle IS null (" + (bundle==null) + ")");
        }

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "getTokenFromIntent: intent IS null (" + (intent==null) + ")");
    }
```

I have this working in a similar module of another project and have been comparing them. The only notable difference is that the working MainActivity extends Activity, and this one extends AppCompatActivity.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136319/bundle-is-always-null), but code seems consistent as it does use a bundle. I also reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107915/bundle-is-null-after-setting-it-in-intent), but mine is basic and does pass values like demonstrated. I reviewed [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097267/android-intent-bundle-always-null) but it did not have a formal answer, but I have an example where I use a bundle which works and so do many of the examples. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106306/intent-bundle-returns-null-every-time) didn't have an accepted answer.

I must be missing something. Maybe it's a stupid little mistake but it's driving me a little crazy.

Comment: Can you confirm this activity is only launching from the MyListenerService?

Comment: I see in the message in Logcat directly before I call startActivity(intent) and then I see the onResume message in Logcat immediately after it.

Comment: What is the launchMode of MainActivity class in manifest file ? is it "singleTop" or something?

Comment: launchMode=singleTask

Comment: If its singleTask override onNewIntent (Intent intent)  method for the intent.

Comment: Great!!! Ty. Answer the question and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we start the activity from Service or with singleTask flag  the Intent should be retrieved from onNewIntent method.

use the following link for more details.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

Comment: SO is great and so are you, Krish. Thank you.